# LayoutConstraints Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: swiftui

I create a simple share button to share some texts. Although the ShareSheet is working, I received unexpected errors messages in my console. I am a beginner level and I have no idea whether should I worry about the error message. Please let me know if there is a better solution for ShareSheet.
The messages are

```
2021-11-22 19:36:03.677822-0500 ZSV5_IDChange[8282:264096] [LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x7feec8925ad0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (16 256; 358 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000038ec4c0>>
2021-11-22 19:36:03.688591-0500 ZSV5_IDChange[8282:264096] [default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
2021-11-22 19:36:03.859368-0500 ZSV5_IDChange[8282:264096] [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x7feec7065a00 Disabling recursion trigger logging
```

Also, I get UIApplication.shared.windows will deprecate in iOS 15. If it is true, I think it will be a smarter choice to use ShareSheet() instead of using private func shareText(text: String). Please have a look at my code before I overcomplicated my question.

Below is my simple code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let cities: String
    let name1: String
    let name2: String
    
    let isFavorite: Bool
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static let dot = [
    DataArray(id: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "John",
        name2: "Mike",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    DataArray(id: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        name1: "Joe",
        name2: "Swift",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    DataArray(id: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Susan",
        name2: "Oliver",
        isFavorite: False),
        
    // There will be a lot of data     
    ]
}

struct TestShareSheet3: View {
    
    var data: DataArray
    @State private var showShareSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button {
                
                self.showShareSheet.toggle()
                
                //shareText(text: "\(data.cities)\n\(data.name1) - \(data.name2)")
                                
            } label: {
                Text("Share")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showShareSheet) {
                // On Dismiss
            } content: {
                ShareSheet(activityItems: ["\(data.cities)\n\(data.name1) - \(data.name2)"])
            }

        }
    }
    
    // This function also has the same issue
    private func shareText(text: String) {
        let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            av.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
            av.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.1, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.3, width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }
}

struct Test2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Testing purposes
        TestShareSheet3(data: ListDataArray.dot[1])
    }
}

struct ShareSheet: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
    
    let activityItems: [Any]
    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil
    let callback: Callback? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lian, do you have a solution for your problem? I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: Which part the error message part or " UIApplication.shared.windows will deprecate in iOS 15"?

Comment: my error is: Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing

Comment: I am not an expert here in SwiftUI. According to my research, these errors are pretty common, and some people claim that it is the Xcode issue. I did try many different approaches as much as you can find on the internet. But I couldn't find a divine solution for these errors. Now, my app is up in the Appstore and working great without any issue. As a beginner to beginner level recommendation, just use simple sheresheet or struct instead of using complicated like mine in the above example. Or if you find a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Liam! I‘m coming to the same result by googling through the Internet. So I‘ll ignore this messages. Thank you!